# Python List Split into a dict

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

There is a python list in the following format

```
mylist = [u'Name:', u'John', , u'Doe', u'Address:', u'Washington Street ',  u'Chicago']
```

There is `':'` right at the end of keys, in this case is `Name` and `Address`.
The new dict should be something like:

```
newdict = {
'Name': '["John", "Doe"]', 
'Address': '["Washington Street", "Chicago"]',
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not necessarily intuitive to use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for this, you can take advantage of how it works:

```
res = {}
for iskey, it in groupby(mylist, lambda s: s.endswith(':')):
    if iskey:
        for k in it:
            key = k[:-1]
            res[key] = []
    else:
        res[key].extend(it)

res
=> {u'Address': [u'Washington Street ', u'Chicago'], u'Name': [u'John', u'Doe']}
```